# How to parse JSON values and populate to combobox using EXTJS 4.2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, extjs, combobox

The method:

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'url',
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 60000,
    params: {
        "perviceTypeId": my.rec.data.prepeId
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var jsonResp = response.responseText;
        console.log("ajax data responseText::" + jsonResp);
        //how to parse value and display and populate to deageType combobox
        var combo = Ext.getCmp('deageType');
    }
});
```

The response is JSON:

```js
{
  "message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "value": "ESS",
      "display": "ESS"
    },
    {
      "value": "ANS",
      "display": "ANS"
    }
  ],
  "errorCode": -1,
  "totalCount": 1,
  "messages": null,
  "resultDate": 1615282701392,
  "success": true
}
```

Comment: Please may you reformat your question?

Comment: Could you add the response content please?

Comment: Check the JSON response.

Comment: @AjayTakur - Populating to combo box means adding them to combo's store right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
var combo = Ext.getCmp('myCombo');
combo.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['value', 'display'],
            data: responseJSON.data
          });
```

Here is functional fiddle with that example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cb0

Comment: @fiddle line no 34 how to retrieve each key value pair of jsonObj.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's a valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should decode the response (using `Ext.JSON.decode`) and bind the store (using `bindStore`) to combo:

Example:

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'url',
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 60000,
    params: {
        "perviceTypeId": my.rec.data.prepeId
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        var combo = Ext.getCmp('deageType');
        combo.bindStore(Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['display', 'value'],
            data: jsonResp['data']
        }));
    }
});
```